# preg_match определить есть ли в строке цифры с дробным остатком

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть несколько строк: 123, 12345, 145.558, 125 рр2312
Как при помощи preg_match проверить есть ли в этих строках цифры?
Т.е. пройти проверку должны целые и дробные значения, а запись рр2312 нет.
У меня получилось вот такое условие:

```
preg_match("/^[\d\+]+$/", $test1)
```

По нему проходят только целые значения. Дробные нет. Переменная $test1 получает приведенные выше значения. Задача осложняется тем, что дробь может обозначаться как точкой, так и запятой.

Comment: Зачем вы в своем варианте добавили знак "+"? По условию считать валидной и строку с выражнием типа `5+6.8`?

Comment: @Sergiks сорян, плюса там быть не должно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, нужно регулярное выражение, буквально соответствующее следующему:

1. одна или несколько цифр
2. (необязательно) одна точка или запятая
3. (необязательно) еще цифры

Тогда примерно так `\d+[\.,]?\d*`:

```
$tests = ["123", "12345", "145.558", "125", "рр2312"];
for( $i=0; $i<count($tests); $i++) {
    printf( "%s\t%s\n", $tests[$i], is_num($tests[$i]));
}

function is_num($s){
    return preg_match( '/^\d+[\.,]?\d*$/', $s);
}

/*  123     1
    12345   1
    145.558 1
    125     1
    рр2312  0
*/
```

По-хорошему, лучше обойтись без регулярных выражений. Вариант: заменить запятые на точки и попробовать относиться как к числу:

```
$output = floatval( str_replace( ',', '.', $input));
```

Этот вариант вернет 0, если получил строку на вход. Т.е. плох он только тем, что не отличает валидное число 0 от невалидной строки.

Comment: Такое число `11.` тоже пропустит, хотя это бред мне кажется. Отрицательные числа не пропустит.

Comment: @Visman предложите набор тестов, пжлст )

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$tests = ['123', '12345', '145.558', '125', 'рр2312', '145,558'];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    if (preg_match('/^([0-9])+([\.,]([0-9])*)?$/', $test)) {
        echo $test;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Для `145,558` выдаст `false`. `> Задача осложняется тем, что дробь может обозначаться как точкой, так и запятой.`

Comment: Отредактировал ответ.

Comment: да я бы и предыдущий вариант оставил, только заменил строку на `var_dump(is_numeric(str_replace(',', '.', $test)));`

Comment: Полная копия ответа Sergiks да еще и с ошибкой `[\.|,]`

Comment: Здесь нет ошибки ;)

Comment: В измененном ответе есть ошибка - `145|558`.

Comment: @AndreiKatalkin пайп в данном случае это символ пайп, а не альтернатива. Поэтому это ошибка.

Comment: Исправил. Спасибо

Comment: Ок, спасибо. Убрал минусик.  А чем Ваш ответ отличается от ответа выше?

Comment: По-другому построено регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 0):

Раз @Andrei Katalkin не хочет возвращаться к первоначальному варианту, то оформлю ответ в виде проверки не через регулярное выражение, а через функцию [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.is-numeric.php)

Чтобы не было проблем с `,`, которая может использоваться вместо `точки` для разделения дробной и целой частей числа, нужно ее перед проверкой заменить через функцию str_replace() на точку.

Сама проверка: `is_numeric(str_replace(',', '.', $str))`

Код теста

```
$tests = array('123', '12345', '145.558', '125', 'pp2312', '145,558', '145.', '.145', '-1');

echo "<pre>\n";
foreach ($tests as $test) {
        echo sprintf("%10s", $test), " --- ", is_numeric(str_replace(',', '.', $test)) ? "true" : "false", "<br>\n";
}
echo "</pre>\n";
```

Результат

```
       123 --- true
     12345 --- true
   145.558 --- true
       125 --- true
    pp2312 --- false
   145,558 --- true
      145. --- true
      .145 --- true
        -1 --- true
```

P.S. Оказывается строки с начальной и конечной точкой тоже числа :P

Comment: По поводу этой правки: я тоже сначала не распознал. Присмотритесь, там вопрос вообще про другое. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30344